# Вводное ли слово «значит» в предложении?

Tags: вводные-слова

«...потому что знание своих прав – это самое основное, чтобы правильно управлять, а значит и эксплуатировать многоквартирный дом, в котором живёшь...» Вводное ли слово «значит» в данном случае?

Comment: Мне кажется, что в предложении есть грамматическая неточность: правильно управлять  (чем?) и эксплуатировать (что?).

Comment: А вообще-то нелогично: знание **своих** прав – это самое основное, чтобы правильно управлять чем-либо(?!). Странная мысль...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так:
«...потому что знание своих прав – это самое основное, чтобы правильно управлять, **а значит**, и эксплуатировать многоквартирный дом, в котором живёшь...»

При наличии союза И  сочетание "а значит" можно убрать из предложения, поэтому в большинстве современных текстов оно обособляется, например:

А потом ему начал сниться сон ― хотя буква «N», кажется, обещала отсутствие «rapid eye movements», **а значит**, и видений. [Виктор Пелевин. Любовь к трем цукербринам (2014)]    (Уж Пелевина-то, наверное, проверяли грамотные корректоры).

А вообще со словами  "значит, а значит" **очень много проблем**. Если говорить кратко, то современная версия постановки запятых отличается от Розенталя, и теперь у нас **двоевластие.** Реформа правописания не была утверждена, действующими остаются правила 1956 года, но в словари (а значит, и в орфографию слов) можно вносить изменения.

**Но пунктуация** ― это же не словари, это правила, но и тут изменения вводятся. А смысл один ― упростить, чтобы не думать много. Общество на это реагирует по-разному ― пишут и так и сяк. Кто по правилам, а кто сопротивляется, так как интуитивно чувствует, что разный смысл не вкладывается в одну примитивную форму.

Обсуждение этой темы (нововведение или новоразведение?)  http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3245

Answer (score 0):

**Вводное**, а значит, требуется обособление.
***Значит*** как вводное слово указывает на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения; то же, что «стало быть, выходит, следовательно».

Answer (score 0):

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%20) говорит, что *а значит* — союз, а значит он отделяется запятой, но не обосабливается (*Проезжаю родные места, и з. увижу своих племянников*.)

**...правильно управлять, а значит и эксплуатировать многоквартирный дом...**

Но должен заметить, это предложение я понимаю так: "правильно управлять = эксплуатировать многоквартирный дом" , a надо бы сказать: "правильно управлять, а значит **правильно** эксплуатировать многоквартирный дом...**

Comment: если изъять «значит», получится белиберда...так и думала...